# Java - Asserting that a class contains text when navigating to a different page that has identical html templates

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I am navigating from one page to another. They both use the same templates the only difference is the text contained within the .image-header__title class. 
I want to select the link to navigate to the other page and assert that is has arrived at the right page by using .gettext() as below:

```
@Test
public void When_I_Click_patterns_page_is_returned() {
    driver.get("https://test.co.uk/fabric-range/");
    String actualString = fp.ClickPattern().getText();
    assertTrue(actualString.contains("Semi-plain Fabrics"));
}


public WebElement ClickPattern() {
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".image-blocks .image-blocks__items .image-blocks__item:nth-child(7) a")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

    WebElement fabricType = wait.until(driver -> driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".image-header__inner .image-header__content .image-header__title")));

    return fabricType;
}
```

I am waiting for the .image-header__title to be present, however as this element is on the initial landing page, the getText() method is not returning the text from the second page but from the first.

Is there anyway I can wait for the second page to be loaded before performing the getText() method?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know if you application reloads the page on "sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)" or does it simply re-render the HTML?  Further more, even if it does reload the page, are post load events used to generate the HTML via javascript?

Selenium will only block while a page is loading, so if "sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)" triggers javascript to re-render the HTML, then it will not wait for that process to finish, and instead return straight away, and as a result exhibit the behavior you see.

**Purely for debugging purposes (!!!!!)** have you tried adding a sleep of a few seconds between "sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)" and the "Webdriver wait"?  Assuming that this does result in the updated text being returned, then this confirms that your application is not reloading and simply re-rendering HTML.

Is there another such as a page loading indicator that your test could hook into instead?  If there was, your "wait until" would be looping until the loading indicator is NOT displayed. Once this had exited, you can continue knowing that your page is ready to be interacted with.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use [`ExpectedConditions#stalenessOf`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#stalenessOf-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-).

1. Grab a reference to an element on Page 1, `e`
2. Trigger the action that changes pages
3. Wait for `e` to go stale
4. Continue the script on Page 2

```
public WebElement ClickPattern() {
    WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".image-blocks .image-blocks__items .image-blocks__item:nth-child(7) a"));
    e.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(e));

    return wait.until(ExpectedCondition.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".image-header__inner .image-header__content .image-header__title")));
}
```

I don't think you need the second wait... but you might so I left it in.